# How to show that the tangent bundle is trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, spheres, tangent-bundle

So I was studying for a test and found this practice problem:

Let $S^1=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, x^2+y^2=1 \}$.

i) Show that $S^1$ is a smooth manifold in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (Done)

ii) Show that the tangent bundle $TS^1$ is trivial.

Now, for ii) I know that you can show the tangent bundle is trivial if you set a fiber-preserving diffeomorphism (however I am not so sure how to do so) or if you show that $TS^1$ is isomorphic to $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$.

Are these the only two options? What are some common tools one can use to show that a tangent bundle is trivial? What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: For $p = (\cos t, \sin t)\in S^1$, consider $v_p = (-\sin t, \cos t) \in T_pS^1 = p^{\perp}$. Then $f(p,w) = (p,\langle v_p,w\rangle)$ is a global trivialization of $TS^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One useful equivalent condition is that an $n$-manifold $M$ has trivial tangent bundle iff there exists a *global frame*, i.e. $n$ vector fields $E_1,\cdots,E_n$ which are everywhere linearly independent (in the sense that $\forall p\in M$, $E_1(p),\cdots,E_n(p)$ form a basis of $T_pM$). This is equivalent to your definition since, given such a global frame, there is an isomorphism $\psi:M\times\mathbb{R}^n\to TM$ given by $\psi(p,v^1,\cdots,v^n)=\sum_iv^iE_i(p)$.

For the circle, this means that $TS$ is trivial iff it admits a nonvanishing tangent vector field.

Comment: How can I determine that nonvanishing tangent vector field?

Comment: Can you think of a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which tangent to, and nonvanishing on, the unit circle? (Try drawing a picture).

Comment: Well, I think that for the circle I could parametrize it with x=cos t and y= sen t, and get the tangent vector field to be described by the gradient. However, the nonvanishing part is the one that cofuses me, how can I confirm that?

Comment: Right. Notice that that vector field would have the form $V(x,y)=(-y,x)$, and thus it is equal to zero iff $x=y=0$, which is not a point on the circle.

Comment: ohhh now it makes sense, thanks a lot

Comment: Is it possible to do this independent of the embedding of the circle in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @MSIS It's possible, but it will depend on how you choose to define the circle.